# changing a code for a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list named `mylist`:

```
mylist = ['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1']
```

and to do some operations I have the following code:

```
left_num = int(mylist[2]) 
right_num = int(mylist[3])
diff= (right_num-left_num)/100 
last_column = mylist[4] + "_part" 


with open("output.txt", "w+") as op_file: 
    op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(mylist[0], mylist[1], left_num, right_num, mylist[4], last_column + str(1)))
    for num in range(2,101):
        temp = int(right_num) 
        right_num = int(right_num + diff) 
        op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(mylist[0], mylist[1], temp, right_num, mylist[4], last_column + str(num)))
```

this code returns a file called `output.txt` with `100 rows`. I am trying to use this code for a `list of lists` like this example:

```
mylist = [['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]
```

I am trying to use the above code for this list of lists and if I manage to do so, I would get a file with `200` rows (100 rows per sublist). I tried the following code just by using for loop but it does not work. do you know how I can change the above code for a `list of lists`:

```
left_num = []
for i in new:
    left_num.append(int(i[2]))


right_num = []
for i in new:
    right_num.append(int(i[3]))


diff = []
for i in new:
    s = (int(i[3])- int(i[2]))/100
    diff.append(s)


last_column = []
for i in new:
    d = i[4] + "_part"
    last_column.append(d)


for x in mylist:
    with open("output.txt", "w+") as op_file: 
        op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(x[0], x[1], left_num, right_num, x[4], last_column + str(1))) 
        for num in range(2,101):
            temp = int(right_num) 
            right_num = int(right_num + diff) # calc difference
            op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(x[0], x[1], temp, right_num, x[4], last_column + str(num)))
```

Comment: I edited the code a bit

Comment: _but it does not work_ --> What does that mean exactly? Do you get an error? Or just not the result you expected? What result did you get instead?

Comment: @ Ocaso Protal in fact still the code returns 100 rows like the original code.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example:

These vars are integer

```
left_num = int(mylist[2]) 
right_num = int(mylist[3])
```

In your second example:

```
left_num = []

for i in new:
    left_num.append(int(i[2]))


right_num = []
for i in new:
    right_num.append(int(i[3]))
```

You can't use lists in "write" like this (2 times, 1 is before the second for loop and the 2. is in the second for loop):

`op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(x[0], x[1], temp, right_num, x[4], last_column + str(num)))`

Call them like (or take any arbitrary value):

`op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(x[0], x[1], temp, right_num[1], x[4], last_column + str(num)))`

`

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [[['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']],[['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]]

with open("output.txt", "w+") as op_file:
    op_file.write('left \t operator \t right \t total \t last col \n')
    for lists in mylist:
        for _list in lists:
            operator = _list[1]
            left_num = _list[2]
            right_num = _list[3]
            last_column = _list[4] + "_part"
            if operator == '+':
                total = int(left_num)+int(right_num)                
            if operator == '-':
                total = int(left_num)-int(right_num)                

            op_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(left_num, operator, right_num, total, last_column))
```

output

```
left     operator    right   total   last col 
11873   +   14409   26282   DDX11L1_part
14361   -   16765   -2404   WASH7P_part
11873   +   14409   26282   DDX11L1_part
14361   -   16765   -2404   WASH7P_part
```

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: not actually. the original code returns what I want but if I have one list. so I want to do the same for a list of lists

Comment: your question is not clear , you can create a function that takes list as input and returns the what needs to be dumped in file.. run a loop through the data and call this function..

Comment: the main problem is in the 2nd part. when writing the file

Comment: if you run the above code on given list you will get the output.

Comment: you are running 4 loops to calculate 4 values,  you can do that within one loop.

Comment: then how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_write_data(_list):
    operator = _list[1]
    left_num = _list[2]
    right_num = _list[3]
    last_column = _list[4] + "_part"
    if operator == '+':
        total = int(left_num)+int(right_num)                
    if operator == '-':
        total = int(left_num)-int(right_num)  
    return '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(left_num, operator, right_num, total, last_column)
```

You have 2 cases

for case 1:

```
mylist1 = ['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1']

with open("output.txt", "w+") as op_file:
    op_file.write('left \t operator \t right \t total \t last col \n')
    op_file.write(get_write_data(mylist1 ))
```

for case 2:

```
mylist2 = [[['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']],[['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]]
with open("output.txt", "w+") as op_file:
    op_file.write('left \t operator \t right \t total \t last col \n')
    for _list in lists:
        op_file.write(get_write_data(_list))
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks but actually for the case 2, mylist2 is not like the one in the question.

Comment: can you send how mylist2 is?

Comment: actually that is in the main text: mylist = [['chr1', '+', '11873', '14409', 'DDX11L1'], ['chr1', '-', '14361', '16765', 'WASH7P']]

Comment: @ Pramit Sawant  i am using python2 BTW.